# Concatenate serialized bits from list into bytes

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I have a python list with data in serialized form `my_list = [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]`

I want to concatenate this 16 bit serialized data into a single int. The 16 bits are stored from MSB to LSB, MSB in index 0

I tried doing bitwise operations with a for loop

```
tmp = 0;
for i in range(0,15)
    tmp = tmp << 1 | my_list[i]

my_int = hex(tmp)

print(my_int)
```

However when I go to print, it displays the incorrect value in hex. Can I perform these bitwise concatenations with the items in the list as ints or do I need to convert them to another data type. Or does this not matter and the error is not coming from concatenating them as ints but from something else?

Comment: `int(''.join([str(x) for x in my_list]), 2)`   Start with a simple example to make sure what you've got is working - e.g. `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]` which should get you 5, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the index by one. The for loop only iterates through values of `i` from 0 to **14** inclusive. To get it to loop through all 16 values, you need to set the endpoint to 16.

```py
for i in range(16):
    tmp = (tmp << 1) | my_list[i]
```

This will output `0x9546`, as expected.

There's also a preferred way of writing this (or use `enumerate` if you also need the index):

```py
for bit in my_list:
    tmp = (tmp << 1) | bit
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mis understanding, you want to convert the list of binary to a single decimal int? You can do this.

```
my_list = [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]

string_ints = [str(i) for i in my_list]
string_ints = ''.join(string_ints)

print(string_ints)
#1001010101000110

num = int(string_ints, 2)
print(num)
#38214
```